# .NET regex for matching words NOT in quotes

Tags: .net, regex

I need a .NET regex that can match on all words excepts words in quotes.

Given a string

```
MARS VENUS EARTH "MERCURY PLUTO SUN MILKYWAY"
```

The regex should return

```
MAR VENUS EARTH
```

Comment: [Here's](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html) much more than what you've asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about replace what is between quotes with empty text like:

This is the rexgex pattern

```
(").*\1
```

This is how to implement it:

```
 var pattern = "(\").*\\1";
 var allText = "MARS VENUS EARTH \"MERCURY PLUTO SUN MILKYWAY\""; 
 Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
 var result = rgx.Replace(allText, "");
 Console.WriteLine("Test= {0}", result);
```

Comment: What is the point to use a capture group and a backreference when you can use literal chars? Other thing, take care to use at least a non-greedy quantifier, otherwise `.*` can match an undefined number of double quotes.